# go to another site after clicking anywhere on background?

Tags: html, css, href

i made a site with gif background, and after clicking anywhere on screen i want to go to another site (something like softlaunch)

my html and css

```css
body {
  background: url(main.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="fav.png" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>@nosleep</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the image to display the way you'd like or do you need help applying the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid javascript by adding an  element which fills the screen; something like this:

```css
body {
  background: hsl(0,0%,50%);
}
a#fill{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  color: color:hsl(0,0%,80%);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 45vh;
  transition: .3s background-color, .3s color;
}
a#fill:hover {
  background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,.3);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/" id="fill">click to visit jsfiddle</a>
```

If you'd prefer, you can also do this with plain javascript if you are so inclined:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
     window.location = 'http://developer.mozilla.org';
  });
});
```

But y

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to handle the click event for you:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", function () { location.href = 'http://developer.mozilla.org'; });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.